# Como dar querySelector em atributos com espaço?

Tags: javascript

Ex: tenho uma `<div arvalue="Teste Novo">`, e

```
document.querySelector("div[arvalue='Teste Novo']").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Se eu tirar o espaço do `arvalue` e colocar `TesteNovo` e mudar a query  `arvalue='TesteNovo'` funciona.

Como posso indicar ao JS que tem um espaço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo assim?

```
document.querySelector("div[arvalue='Teste%20Novo']").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Ou então:

```
document.querySelector("div[arvalue='Teste\\ Novo']").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```